# Localized value from ExpandEnvironmentStrings

Tags: c++, winapi, internationalization, filesystems, environment-variables

In a code, I am using ExpandEnvironmentStrings function to get the value of %USERPROFILE%. I am getting the EN value even on Localized OS such as German. For example, I am getting the value as "C\Users\Administrator". But I am interested in the Localized value such as c:\Benutzer\Administrator.

For now, I am considering using SHGetFileInfo by passing the foldername returned by ExpandEnvironmentStrings. That actually works only with the ultimate folder of the path i.e "Administrator" in this case and not "Users". To use SHGetFileInfo, I need to break the path in individual folders and after getting localized value, join the strings.

Is there a better and more appropriate method to get the complete value localized?

Comment: Could you explain more exactly what is your goal and what is the way to archive the goal. You mix different things currently. Do you need to get all user profiles on the computer of you need the folder of the current user. Do use use central profiles (saved on the server) in your environment? Do you mean `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`, `SHGetFolderPath` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath` and not `SHGetFileInfo` probably?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using environmental values to find shell-related folders. You should use [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180%28VS.85%29.aspx) with CSIDL_PROFILE on XP and earlier, or [SHGetKnownFolderIDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Vista and higher with FOLDERID_Profile. I believe both of these will return the localized locations.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable should be accurate as of the time your program starts up (which is when its environment variables' values are established). That's all `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` will look at. It doesn't translate into other languages. If the value of your environment variable is "C:\Users\Administrator," then that's what the API will expand it to.

If you want to get the path to the current user's home directory, call [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx).